# Prove that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^k\,j\,\binom{n}{j}\,\binom{n-j}{2k-2j}\,2^{2k-2j}=n\binom{2n-2}{2k-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, analytic-combinatorics

I encountered this in my homework. I derived two ways to solve the problem and the answer which I have tested using programming, seem to be the same,  but I am not sure how to prove this equation.

> Let $n$ and $k$ be nonnegative integers with $k\leq n$.  Prove that $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^k\,j\,\binom{n}{j}\,\binom{n-j}{2k-2j}\,2^{2k-2j}=n\binom{2n-2}{2k-2}\,.$$

The original problem is the following:

> A shoe rack has n pairs of shoes.  Of those, 2k individual shoes are chosen at random, k ≤ n. Calculate the expected number of matching shoes among 2k chosen shoes.

The left hand side is from directly calculating expectation, while the right hand side is using sum of indicator variables of each pair being chosen. The expectation is just the equation divided by $\binom{2n}{2k}$.

Comment: Are you saying there was a problem you solved in two ways, one giving the left-hand side, one giving the right-hand side? Then that proves the equation. What's more, any attempt we make to prove it on our own might accidentally do exactly what you did, unless you edit your question to show what.

Comment: Hi, I added the original problem for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity is equivalent to
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\,\binom{n-1-i}{2k-2-2i}\,4^{2k-2-i}=4^{k-1}\binom{2n-2}{2k-2}$$
where $i=j-1$.
By considering the Cauchy product, the LHS is
$$4^{2k-2}[z^{2k-2}](1+z)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^{n-1}$$
which can be written as
$$4^{2k-2}[z^{2k-2}]\left(1+\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2n-2}$$
that is the RHS.

Comment: Can you please share what the z is and how you apply the Cauchy product? Thanks!!

Comment: @Yilin $z$ is a dummy variable. The answer shows the claim equates two expressions for a coefficient in a certain power series. A simpler example of this strategy is$$\begin{align}\binom{m+n}{k}&=[z^k](1+z)^{m+n}\\&=[z^k](1+z)^m(1+z)^n\\&=\sum_{j=0}^k[z^j](1+z)^m[z^{k-j}](1+z)^n\\&=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{m}{j}\binom{n}{k-j}.\end{align}$$

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Using coefficient extractors we present a minor variation and seek to
prove

$$\sum_{j=1}^k {n-1\choose j-1} {n-j\choose 2k-2j} 2^{2k-2j}
= {2n-2\choose 2k-2}$$

or alternatively

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {n-1\choose j} {n-j-1\choose 2k-2j-2} 2^{2k-2j-2}
= {2n-2\choose 2k-2}.$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {n-1\choose j} 2^{2k-2j-2}
[z^{2k-2j-2}] (1+z)^{n-j-1}
\\ = 2^{2k-2} [z^{2k-2}] (1+z)^{n-1}
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {n-1\choose j} (1+z)^{-j} z^{2j} 2^{-2j}.$$

The coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the sum:

$$ 2^{2k-2} [z^{2k-2}] (1+z)^{n-1}
\sum_{j\ge 0} {n-1\choose j} (1+z)^{-j} z^{2j} 2^{-2j}
\\ =  2^{2k-2} [z^{2k-2}] (1+z)^{n-1}
\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^{n-1}
\\ =  2^{2k-2} [z^{2k-2}]
\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{4}\right)^{n-1}
= [z^{2k-2}]
\left(1+2z+z^2\right)^{n-1}
\\ = [z^{2k-2}] (1+z)^{2n-2} = {2n-2\choose 2k-2}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: $+1$. Pretty fine !!!.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the RHS term, multiply it by $x^{2k}$, and sum over $k$
$$
\eqalign{
  & F_R (x^{\,2} ,n) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
 {n\left( \matrix{  2n - 2 \cr   2k - 2 \cr}  \right)x^{\;2k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = n\,x^{\,2} \,\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\left( {1\, \le } \right)\,k}
 {\left( \matrix{  2\left( {n - 1} \right) \cr   2\left( {k - 1} \right) \cr}  \right)
\left( {x^{\,2} } \right)^{\;k - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = n\,x^{\,2} \,\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\left( {1\, \le } \right)\,k}
 {\left( \matrix{  2\left( {n - 1} \right) \cr   2k \cr}  \right)\left( {x^{\,2} } \right)^{\;k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {{n\,x^{\,2} } \over 2}\left( {\left( {1 + x} \right)^{2n - 2}  + \left( {1 - x} \right)^{2n - 2} } \right) \cr} 
$$

Then we do the same on the LHS
$$
\eqalign{
  & F_L (x^{\,2} ,n) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {j\left( \matrix{  n \cr   j \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  n - j \cr   2k - 2j \cr}  \right)2^{\,2k - 2j} x^{\;2k} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = n\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - 1 \cr   j - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  n - j \cr   2\left( {k - j} \right) \cr}  \right)
 \left( {2^{\,2} x^{\,2} } \right)^{\,\left( {k - j} \right)} x^{\;2j} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = n\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - 1 \cr   j - 1 \cr}  \right)x^{\;2j} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\left( {k - j} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - j \cr   2\left( {k - j} \right) \cr}  \right)
 \left( {2^{\,2} x^{\,2} } \right)^{\,\left( {k - j} \right)} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {n \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - 1 \cr   j - 1 \cr}  \right)x^{\;2j}
 \left( {\left( {1 + 2x} \right)^{n - j}  + \left( {1 - 2x} \right)^{n - j} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{nx^{\;2n} } \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - 1 \cr   n - j \cr}  \right)x^{\;2j - 2n} 
 \left( {\left( {1 + 2x} \right)^{n - j}  + \left( {1 - 2x} \right)^{n - j} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{nx^{\;2n} } \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n - j}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - 1 \cr   n - j \cr}  \right)
 \left( {\left( {{{1 + 2x} \over {x^{\;2} }}} \right)^{n - j}
  + \left( {{{1 - 2x} \over {x^{\;2} }}} \right)^{n - j} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{nx^{\;2n} } \over 2}\left( {\left( {1 + {{1 + 2x} \over {x^{\;2} }}} \right)^{n - 1}
  + \left( {1 + {{1 - 2x} \over {x^{\;2} }}} \right)^{n - 1} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{nx^{\;2} } \over 2}\left( {\left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,2\left( {n - 1} \right)}
  + \left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2\left( {n - 1} \right)} } \right) \cr} 
$$

The two polynomials are equal, so must be their coefficients.